# Matching Values Between Two Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, match

I'm trying to find whether a value exist in an array, like the below (which works):

```
while x < mySegmentXMax && contains(myOtherArray, 41) {                             
     myPhysicsBodyCount = myPhysicsBodyCount + 1
     x = x + 1
}
```

However, when I try to make this dynamic and use another array that holds the values, I keep getting errors no matter what I try. Example of what I've tryied below:

```
while x < mySegmentXMax && contains(myOtherArray, myArray[Int(x)] as NSObject) {
    myPhysicsBodyCount = myPhysicsBodyCount + 1
    x = x + 1
}
```

Note: myArray[Int(x)] as NSObject equal 41, so I should get the same result.

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What the array contains?

Comment: nevermind, it is a swift method, you didn't declare one yourself right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, maybe I'm missing something and thats why this is not working. This is properly not what your talking about, but myArray = [41,41,41,1,41] and myOtherArray = [41, 42].

Comment: so why the cast to NSObject? what is the error message?

Comment: I cast to NSObject only because I've been receiving other error through out my code when I don't, for example if myArray[Int(myElementCount - 1)] as! NSObject != 41.

Comment: The error I'm receive in this instance is "Could not find an overload for '<' that accepts the supplied arguments. But when I change from myOtherArray, myArray[Int(x)] as NSObject) to contains(myOtherArray, 41) I don't get this error.

Comment: can you try: contains(myOtherArray, myArray[Int(x)]) and tell me what message you are getting

Comment: is `mySegmentXMax` always smaller than `myArray.count`?

Comment: Giorashc, I get the same error message when I changed it

Comment: Jacobson, mySegmentXMax should equal myArray.count. x should alway be less then mySegmentXMax

Comment: What exactly is inside `myArray`?

Comment: I tried this code and it worked. can you post the definitions of the arrays and the other variables use above?

Comment: [41,41,41,1,41], but this does change through the program

Comment: Those seems to be just `Ints` then. How about `myOtherArray`?

Comment: myOtherArray = [41, 42]

Comment: @Jarron try your code here: http://www.runswiftlang.com/ (just for the while loop)

Comment: x = current myArray number count, mySegmentXMax = myArray.count, myOtherArray = [41,42], myArray = [41,41,41,1,41]. Hope this helps

Comment: I tried your code, removed casting to `NSObject` and had no problems compiling it. Problem probably lies with the initialization of your arrays. Also, with the code you have now, you only want to add till `contains` is `false`?

Comment: Thanks Jacobson, once I casted the array as NSInteger, I stopped receive the error and my code worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This has solve my problem, I'm starting to think that my array went out of range even though it never specified that as the error. Below is what I have done.

```
while x < mySegmentXMax && contains(myOtherArray, myInt) {
      myPhysicsBodyCount = myPhysicsBodyCount + 1
      x = x + 1
      if x < mySegmentXMax {
            myInt = myArray[Int(x)] as! NSInteger
      }
}
```

Wait, this code is better

```
while x < mySegmentXMax && contains(myOtherArray, myArray[Int(x)] as! NSInteger) {
      myPhysicsBodyCount = myPhysicsBodyCount + 1
      x = x + 1
}
```

Thanks Giorashc and Jacobson for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to count the amount of elements in myArray that are also in myOtherArray? You could just do: `myArray.filter{contains(myOtherArray, $0)}.count`, and then add that to `myPhysicsBodyCount` and `x`

Comment: Not in this case, but I'll keep your comment in mind if I ever need it.

Comment: what about `Set(myArray).subtracting(myOtherArray)`?